# Solving eigenvector in an ODE for given eigvenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am kind of confused how to get the underlined $\cosh(\lambda y)$ and $\sinh(\lambda y)$ when the eigenvalue is $-\lambda$. I understand that when it is $+\lambda$ (i.e. when I have an equation like this $ Y'' + \lambda Y= 0$, so I can use the characteristic polynomial which in this case is $r^2+\lambda=0$, and then get the solution to be $y=A\cos (\sqrt\lambda y)+ B\sin(\sqrt\lambda y)$. But how about when $\lambda = \text{negative}$? (i.e. when $ Y'' - \lambda Y= 0)$?

how to get the solution of $y=\cosh(\lambda y) + \sinh(\lambda y)?$
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic equation for the ODE $Y'' - \lambda^2Y = 0$ is $x^2 - \lambda^2$ so
$$Y = C_1e^{\lambda y} + C_2e^{-\lambda y}$$
is the general solution. Since

$$
e^{\lambda y} = \frac{e^{\lambda y} + e^{-\lambda y}}{2} + \frac{e^{\lambda y} - e^{-\lambda y}}{2} = \cosh(\lambda y) + \sinh(\lambda y)
$$
and
$$
e^{-\lambda y} = \frac{e^{\lambda y} + e^{-\lambda y}}{2} - \frac{e^{\lambda y} - e^{-\lambda y}}{2} = \cosh(\lambda y) + \sinh(\lambda y)
$$ the solution can be re-written in the form

$$
C\cosh(\lambda y) + D\sinh(\lambda y)
$$

Comment: Hi, is it possible to know how to get the $Y= C_1 e^{\lambda y} + C_2 e^{-\lambda y} $ equation?

Comment: It comes from solving the homogeneous Linear ODE with constant coefficients. Any text on ODEs should contain an explanation of the method.

Comment: oh I will look it up then, thanks a lot.